# Responsive design method for collapsing a div

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm using a CSS theme with a sidebar navigation menu. I'd like to add a button, to let users close the sidebar.

I'm familiar with jQuery toggle, show, hide, etc... and I could write the script to hide and show the div a number of ways, but is there a compliant way to do it, that will work on most browsers and phones?

Is there a better option other than show hide in jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: i think most browsers and phones will support toggle . go for your current solution.

Comment: @PriyankPatel yes i'm sure toggle is supported and seems to be a simple jquery solution just wondering what if any other methods people use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most proper way would be to just toggle a class and to the rest with css...

```
var $yourSidebar = $(".sidebar");
$(document).on("click.toggleNav touch.toggleNav", ".yourTriggerButton", function(){ 
 $yourSidebar.toggleClass("open");
});
```

in your css, you can use media queries to make the navigation behave differently for each resolution range and even animate properly using css transitions.

This will work on almost all mobile and desktop devices.

DMEO: http://jsfiddle.net/a24fQ/

Comment: Would CSS transitions be better than using a jQuery effect?

Comment: @Anagio definitely. CSS ist for Style. JavaScript should be only for the application logic... Generally you want to separate the application logic from the design & animation. Beside that it performs much better especially on mobile devices..

Comment: Thanks works great, I forked that fiddle right into my account

Answer (score 0):

u can use css visibility attribute and make visibility: hidden on click event.
like `jQuery (selector).css('visibility','hidden');`

Answer (score 0):

use this in class...

```
div
{
display:none;
}
div:hover
{
display:block;
}
```

Comment: :hover... hover with your finger over your mobile phone?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no actual a better way, then using JS. Becuase you need to handle toggling  on button click. Using of jQuery, ExtJS, or straight JS it is a questions of using of tool. t So, using of JavaScript this is absolutly normal in this case.