# which is best practice or more efficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was practicing some jQuery when I found [this tutorial](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu). It does the exact same thing as I was trying with JavaScript but uses pure CSS3. I figure it is best to learn what's right then to have to relearn, so that is why I am asking if there is a benefit of one to another or is it just preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use CSS when given the opportunity except in cases where you need to use logic/arithmetic.

A similar question was asked here: [Responsive design method for collapsing a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716885/responsive-design-method-for-collapsing-a-div)

Comment: OK, Thanks. I am finding that a lot of the answers are out there but I don't know what things are called or what to search. Hopefully one day I will be answering the stupid questions instead of asking them

Comment: You are most welcomed, dont forget to mark as correct and btw, check these out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS. MDN is IMO the best source of information for CSS/JS...

Answer (score 2):

The CSS solution may be easier and will probably be more efficient, but it produces a much more basic solution.

For example, with the pure CSS solution, as soon as you move the mouse outside of an item, it loses focus and closes.  This can be annoying for users if the menu has many levels or the items are small enough that the mouse may accidentally stray outside.

Using javascript, it is possible to keep menu items open even if the mouse moves outside.  It also allows for more customization of options like animations and delays.  There are plenty of [jQuery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/?s=dropdown) that make dropdown menus easy.